# Is there a document describing Silverlight 2.0 security considerations?

Tags: silverlight-2.0

Our IT guys haven't worked with Silverlight 2.0 yet and I am asking them to roll it out across the organisation. They would like to see a document from Microsoft that describes the security implications for the network. Can anyone point me to one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "[Security Guidance for Writing and Deploying Silverlight Applications](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=7cef15a8-8ae6-48eb-9621-ee35c2547773)" Whitepaper available from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best one if you're concerned with Silverlight's use of sockets [Silverlight Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296248(VS.95).aspx).

Comment: Not exactly what I was after but +1 because it is interesting :-)